# How to customise UITabBarController for changing opening UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I had TabBarController with two items:

First item segue to:

`NavigationController1->ViewController11->ViewController12`

Second item segue to:

`NavigationController2->ViewController21`

I go to `ViewController12` through `ViewController11`, then click item2 and then click item1 and I comeback to `ViewController12`, but I want to see `ViewController11`.

How can I do it?

Comment: Swift or Objectiv-C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to subclass UITabBarController:

```
import UIKit

class MVTabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.delegate = self
    }

    func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
        var navigationController = viewController.navigationController
        if navigationController != nil {
            navigationController!.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
        }
    }
}
```

In your Storyboard:

[image]

Try this, it's only a idea, not tested.

**EDIT**

```
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {

    if viewController.isKindOfClass(UINavigationController) {
        var navigationController = viewController as UINavigationController
        navigationController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
}
```